# Is there a stable file copy utility built into windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, file-management, powershell

I am trying to copy some files from a shared network drive to my desktop when I use `xcopy /C` sooner or later I get an error `The handle is invalid`. Is there perhaps another way to copy the files so that I don't run into that problem? The only tools I can use are the those already built into windows 7 (i.e. powershell and cmd). Also no ftp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29) I use it for copying files over an SDSL connection between two sites.